# Switch in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

I was writing a java program that had a switch in a for loop, and the switch wouldn't loop. the code read as follows:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Translate {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input=null;
        int i;
        char letter;
            do{             
                out.print("Enter a word to translate");
                input=keyboard.next();
            } while(input==null);
            out.println(" ");//blank line, aesthetics.
            for (i=0;i==input.length();i++);//the misbehaving loop{
                letter=input.charAt(i);
                switch(letter){
                case 'a':{
                    out.print("(-)");
                    break;
                }case 'b':{ 
                    out.print("(-|)");
                    break;
                }case 'c':{
                    out.print("(-\\)");
                    break;
                }case 'd':{
                    out.print("(|--)");
                    break;
                }case 'e':{
                    out.print("(|||)");
                    break;
                }case 'f':{
                    out.print("(|-)");
                    break;
                }default:{
                    out.print("GOODBYE");
                }
            }
        }
       }
 }
```

Comment: What do you think `i == input.length()` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 mistakes in this

```
for (i=0;i==input.length();i++);//the misbehaving loop{
```

1. `i==input.length()` should be `i<input.length()`
2. there should not be `;` after for loop

`for (i=0;i==input.length();i++);` should be `for (i=0;i<input.length();i++)`

Comment: Er, I agree with `;` being int he wrong place, but are you sure you want to _assign_ `i` in the loop condition? I'd guess a `<` is what he wants.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson sorry I was in bit hurry

Answer (score 0):

The loop is misbehaving because the `switch` statement is not the part of the `for` loop. The loop is terminating right where it is declared. This is because of the `;` next to the for-loop.